# numpy multidimensional indexing and diagonal symmetries

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a pretty large numpy array ...

```
power = ...
print power.shape
>>> (3, 10, 10, 19, 75, 10, 10)
```

which is symmetric w.r.t. the 10x10 parts, i.e the following 2-d matrices are symmetric

```
power[i, :, :, j, k, l, m]
power[i, j, k, l, m, :, :]
```

for all values of i, j, k, l, m

Can I utilize this factor-4 gain? E.g. when saving the matrix to file (50 mb with savez_compressed)

My attempt:

```
size = 10
row_idx, col_idx = np.tril_indices(size)
zip_idx = zip(row_idx, col_idx)
print len(zip_idx), zip_idx[:5]
>>> 55 [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
all_idx = [(r0, c0, r1, c1) for (r0, c0) in zip_idx for (r1, c1) in zip_idx]
print len(all_idx), all_idx[:5]
>>> 3025 [(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 2, 0), (0, 0, 2, 1)]
a, b, c, d = zip(*all_idx)
tril_part = np.transpose(s.power, (0, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 6))[:,:,:, a, b, c, d]
print tril_part.shape
>>> (3, 19, 75, 3025)
```

This seems ugly, but "works" ... once I can also get back to power from tril_part ...

I guess this yields two qurestions:

1. Better way of going from power to tril_part?
2. How to go from tril_part to power?

Edit: The "size" comment is clearly valid, but please ignore it :-) IMHO the indexing part of the question stands alone. I've been finding myself wanting to do similar indexing for smaller matrices.

Comment: The array is realistically not that big, are you sure it is really worth saving 35mb?

Comment: @Ophion: Actually it "is". It's the output of 3*10*10*19 simulations resulting in 75 10x10 matrices. I find it convenient and natural to save it like this, and use accessor functions for "slicing".

Comment: what is the dtype of `power`?

Comment: If you care about performance and speed, you will probably get better results using HDF5 (via Pytables, for example). You can tune the compression levels to better suit your needs, and the algorithm will probably exploit partially the symmetries anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path. Using `np.tril_indices` you can indeed smartly index these lower triangles. What remains to be improved is the actual indexing/slicing of the data.

Please try this (copy and pasteable):

```
import numpy as np
shape = (3, 10, 10, 19, 75, 10, 10)
p = np.arange(np.prod(shape)).reshape(shape)  # this is not symmetric, but not important

ix, iy = np.tril_indices(10)
# In order to index properly, we need to add axes. This can be done by hand or with this
ix1, ix2 = np.ix_(ix, ix)
iy1, iy2 = np.ix_(iy, iy)

p_ltriag = p[:, ix1, iy1, :, :, ix2, iy2]
print p_ltriag.shape  # yields (55, 55, 3, 19, 75), axis order can be changed if needed

q = np.zeros_like(p)
q[:, ix1, iy1, :, :, ix2, iy2] = p_ltriag  # fills the lower triangles on both sides
q[:, ix1, iy1, :, :, iy2, ix2] = p_ltriag  # fills the lower on left, upper on right
q[:, iy1, ix1, :, :, ix2, iy2] = p_ltriag  # fills the upper on left, lower on right
q[:, iy1, ix1, :, :, iy2, ix2] = p_ltriag  # fills the upper triangles on both sides
```

The array `q` now contains a symmetrized version of `p` (where the upper triangles were replaced with the content of the lower triangles). Note that the last line contains `iy` and `ix` indices in inversed order, essentially creating a transpose of the lower triangular matrix.

**Comparison on lower triangles**
In order to compare back, we set all the upper triangles to `0`

```
ux, uy = np.triu_indices(10)
p[:, ux, uy] = 0
q[:, ux, uy] = 0
p[:, :, :, :, :, ux, uy] = 0
q[:, :, :, :, :, ux, uy] = 0

print ((p - q) ** 2).sum()  # euclidean distance is 0, so p and q are equal

print ((p ** 2).sum(), (q ** 2).sum())  # prove that not all entries are 0 ;) - This has a negative result due to an overflow
```

Comment: I am not sure though whether it makes sense to do this compression if you need to reinflate afterwards.

Comment: np.ix_ certainly seems to be the way to go. Adding it to my toolbox. However, when I do np.allclose on the original (p) and the result (q) I get False. Also, why don't understand why you use indices 1 and 2 and don't reuse ix and iy? readability? Is it really sufficient to only use 2 indices and not 4, i.e. all 55*55 combinations? I played around with the latter approach, but get the 'dimension too large in fancy indexing' ValueError.

Comment: `np.ix_` is indeed a useful command to know. You are getting `False` because `p` and `q` only coincide on the lower triangular half and `q` is a symmetrized version of `p` (see my comment in the code where I generate `p` - it is not symmetric). I created `ix1` and `ix2` for readability and generalizability. In your case you can also write `ix[:, np.newaxis]` for `ix1` and `ix[np.newaxis, :]` for `ix2`. The adding of different axes is very important, since this way numpy will generate the cartesian product of the indices. Check the dimension of the output array (there are 2 axes of size 55).

Comment: I set the upper triangular part of p and q to zero, but still get False for allclose. Can you add a comparisson part to the code to verify your claim?

Comment: Indeed, I got the assignments wrong and have edited. Thanks very much for catching this! I had only set "lower/lower" and "upper/upper", forgetting the locations corresponding to "upper/lower" and "lower/upper". I put comments next to the assignments to explain this. There are now 4 assignments instead of 2.